# Running Selenium + Geckodriver on Linux with no GUI

Tags: selenium, ubuntu, webdriver, geckodriver

I am able to run my test in headless mode using Linux Mint. I then created a VPS with no GUI. The VPS is running Ubuntu 17.10, I installed Firefox on it by running `apt install firefox` but I get the following error when I run my Selenium test. Anyone has had success running Firefox headless mode on a Linux with no GUI?

```
System info: host: 'localhost', ip: '127.0.0.1', os.name: 'Linux', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '4.13.0-36-generic', java.version: '1.8.0_151'
Driver info: driver.version: RemoteWebDriver
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverCommandExecutor.execute(DriverCommandExecutor.java:92)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:601)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.get(RemoteWebDriver.java:325)
    at mypackage.MyProject.start(MyProject.java:40)
    at mypackage.MyProject2.run(MyProject2.java:25)
    at mypackage.Main.main(Main.java:32)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.jarinjarloader.JarRsrcLoader.main(JarRsrcLoader.java:58)
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Failed to connect to localhost/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:18384
    at okhttp3.internal.connection.RealConnection.connectSocket(RealConnection.java:240)
    at okhttp3.internal.connection.RealConnection.connect(RealConnection.java:158)
    at okhttp3.internal.connection.StreamAllocation.findConnection(StreamAllocation.java:256)
    at okhttp3.internal.connection.StreamAllocation.findHealthyConnection(StreamAllocation.java:134)
    at okhttp3.internal.connection.StreamAllocation.newStream(StreamAllocation.java:113)
    at okhttp3.internal.connection.ConnectInterceptor.intercept(ConnectInterceptor.java:42)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:147)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:121)
    at okhttp3.internal.cache.CacheInterceptor.intercept(CacheInterceptor.java:93)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:147)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:121)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.BridgeInterceptor.intercept(BridgeInterceptor.java:93)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:147)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RetryAndFollowUpInterceptor.intercept(RetryAndFollowUpInterceptor.java:125)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:147)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:121)
    at okhttp3.RealCall.getResponseWithInterceptorChain(RealCall.java:200)
    at okhttp3.RealCall.execute(RealCall.java:77)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.internal.OkHttpClient.execute(OkHttpClient.java:104)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.internal.OkHttpClient.execute(OkHttpClient.java:54)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.HttpCommandExecutor.execute(HttpCommandExecutor.java:157)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverCommandExecutor.execute(DriverCommandExecutor.java:83)
    ... 10 more
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:350)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:206)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:188)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:589)
    at okhttp3.internal.platform.Platform.connectSocket(Platform.java:125)
    at okhttp3.internal.connection.RealConnection.connectSocket(RealConnection.java:238)
    ... 31 more
```

Comment: Can you update the question with the log messages generated before `System info` line which would be crucial to debug the issue?

Comment: I had forgotten about the log messages as I had them disabled. I will run this again tomorrow with the log messages as update this question.

Comment: I did a clean VPS install and everything is working fine now. I must have made a mistake somewhere

Comment: Once you figure out what went wrong or what that mistake was, if you add it to this post as an answer someone in the future will appreciate you.

Comment: @Rescis I will, are you having issues?

Comment: I'm not personally.  Didn't see you had been on the site for a bit and am used to just reminding people that they can answer their own questions.